# Maximum servers in a ZooKeeper ensemble cluster?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Use case: 100 Servers in a pool; I want to start a ZooKeeper service on each Server and Server applications (ZooKeeper client) will use the ZooKeeper cluster (read/write). Then there is no single point of failure.

Is this solution possible for this use case? What about the performance?

What if there are 1000 Servers in the pool?

Answer (score 5):

If you are simply trying to avoid a *single* point of failure, then you only need 3 servers.  In a 3 node ensemble, a single failure can be tolerated with the remaining 2 nodes forming the quorum.  The more servers you have the worse write performance will be.  And 100 **servers** is the extreme of this, if ZK can even handle it.

However, having that many **clients** is no problem at all.  Zookeeper has active deployments with many more than 1000 *clients*.  If you find that you need more servers to handle your read load, you can always add [Observers](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperObservers.html).  I highly recommend you join the [list serve](http://zookeeper.apache.org/lists.html).  It is an excellent way to quickly have your questions answered, and likely in much more detail than anyone will give you on SO.

Comment: Thanks Jared. My case is a little special: every server in this pool could poweroff any time (duo to a power saving policy). So in theory, I have to start a ZooKeeper service on each Server to prevent the cluster down. It seems the best solution is to run the ZooKeeper service out of the pool. But that schema doesn't fit our product well. Here, I hope someone can tell me the maximum number of Servers in a ZooKeeper ensemble cluster: is the performance acceptable for 100? 1000?

Comment: @zhigang I highly encourage you to ask on the list serve (link in my post).  You will get exactly the answer you seek there.  And if ZK doesn't support it, you will get great suggestions on how to achieve your end goal.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe zookeeper is not the right tool?

[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) does what you want, I think.  You can hundreds of peers, and if the master is lost a new one is elected from all the peers.

You don't need to use all of hazel cast.  You can just use the maps, or just the worker pools, or just the synchronisation primitives, or just the messaging etc.