# Whats the maximum size of the zookeeper ensemble

Tags: apache-zookeeper

How many nodes at max can be part of the Zookeeper ensemble , is it 255 . If you want to go beyond that should there be multiple ensembles ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question: [Maximum servers in a ZooKeeper ensemble cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348409/maximum-servers-in-a-zookeeper-ensemble-cluster)

Not sure about the actual limits in ZK code, but any cluster of size larger than e.g. 13 would be really strange. At some point write performance would start to suffer significantly.

Proper scaling would be having multiple clusters for different use cases. Alternatively, using Observers which don't affect write speed.